# Issuing Github commands on Git Bash when not connected to the internet

Tags: github, git-bash

Due to permissions on our network, the account I use to run "Git Bash" (on Windows) does not have internet access. As described here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js, I want to issue this command:

$ git clone git://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.git pdfjs

And then issue:

$ make

Obviously, I get an error from the first command:

fatal: unable to connect to github.com

Can I somehow download the project from github and do this all from my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/zipball/master

There's a zip button in the upper left hand corner, by the git repository link. If you can get that zip on to this machine somehow, you have everything you need.

Comment: I've got that zip file downloaded. What is the command I need to run in Git Bash?

Comment: You don't need to run anything in git bash, it's just the source tree. Just run make.

Comment: Ok. I'm very new to all this. How I run "make" against this zip file?

Comment: But it seems he/she doesn't care about history, just being able to run make.

Comment: @knowledgequester Unzip the file, go into the directory you just created, and run make. That is assuming you have make installed. Do you have cygwin or something similar installed?

Comment: I don't think so. I just installed "Git for Windows" as described here: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

Comment: Woah, I think we need to take a step backwards here. Getting this code to compile on windows isn't simple. Minimally, you need a make program, python, and a bash like shell.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I guess I just want the output from the "make", which looks like it just combines all the javascript files into one file. It looks like the zip file doesn't include this combined mega pdf.js file.

Comment: In that case (I haven't verified this) couldn't you just appends the files to one another?

Comment: yeah - or even better, I could just view source on the example page (http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) and then get it from there. Thanks for the clarifications.